# Exibir todos os diretórios e arquivos contidos neles

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou tentando montar uma árvore de arquivos onde além de exibir os diretórios do computador seja exibido também os seus arquivos. O código que fiz abaixo está listando apenas o diretório especificado, no caso o `C:\`. Porém os diretórios contidos dentro do `C:` como por exemplo "Arquivos de Programas" não exibe o que tem dentro.

```
package arvore;

import java.io.File;

public class Arvore {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\");

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("Este é Arquivo " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("***ESTE E DIRETÓRIO " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

A pergunta é como ficaria pra exibir todos inclusive subdiretórios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa recursividade:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\");

    for (File arquivo : folder.listFiles()) {
        listarArquivos(arquivo);
    }

}

public static void listarArquivos(File raiz) {
    if (raiz.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Este é Arquivo " + raiz.getName());
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("***ESTE E DIRETÓRIO " + raiz.getName());
    for (File no : raiz.listFiles()) {
        listarArquivos(no);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse aqui lista tudo! Sub-diretórios, e todos os arquivos.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;


public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path startPath = Paths.get("c:/");
            Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                        BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                    System.out.println("Diretório: " + dir.toString());
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                    System.out.println("Arquivo: " + file.toString());    
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sim realmente eu dei uma olhada nele e não falta nada, a questão é... E se eu tivesse mais de um diretório ? Teria como mostrar todos e seus respectivos diretórios?